# Input/output error when trying to remove a file in NFS

Tags: nfs, rm

I am trying to remove a file that is located on an [NFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_File_System) storage device.

```
 rm model_parameters_epoch_000.npz
```

I get the error message:

```
rm: cannot remove ‘model_parameters_epoch_000.npz’: Input/output error
```

What could be the issue?

My machine runs on Ubuntu 14.04.4 LTS. Shortly before the issue, I had maxed out the disk space. I did successfully remove some files before the `Input/output error` issue appeared.

Comment: Can you access the file from the server side?

Comment: @bsd I don't have access to the NFS server